# Unknown column error with LEFT JOIN Alias

Tags: mysql

I was trying to add aliases to my left joins so that I could do two joins on the same table (different key) but ran in to this problem. I've stripped down the query to where the problem is to keep things simple.

```
SELECT stock_items.id AS stockid, exchange_rates.rate AS rate
FROM stock_items
LEFT JOIN exchange_rates AS exr ON stock_items.currency = exchange_rates.id
```

When I run this query I get

1054 - Unknown column 'exchange_rates.id' in 'on clause'

However if I remove the alias so it looks like this...

```
SELECT stock_items.id AS stockid, exchange_rates.rate AS rate 
FROM stock_items 
LEFT JOIN exchange_rates ON stock_items.currency = exchange_rates.id
```

This query runs fine... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add an `alias`, you should use it in your `join`.

```
SELECT stock_items.id AS stockid, exr.rate AS rate
FROM stock_items
LEFT JOIN exchange_rates exr ON stock_items.currency = exr.id
```

Comment: AS is optional, it may be used (for better readability) - or not.